# npm thinks node is out of date, but it isn't

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I'm trying to install node-gyp. I run

```
 sudo npm install -g node gyp
```

I get an error that says it requires node 0.8.0 and says that I'm running 0.6.12. The thing is, I'm not. I'm using NVM and I'm currently runnign 0.11.something. When I run node -v I get

```
 v0.11.1
```

Why does NPM think I'm running node 0.6? I've set the default NVM to the latest.

The exact error is:

```
Unsupported
Not compatible with your version of node/npm: request@2.21.0
Required ["node >= 0.8.0"]
Actual   {"npm":"1.1.4","node":"0.6.12"}
```

I'm running ubuntu.

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: updated with the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I had used

```
apt-get install nodejs
```

when I configured my system. That install had issues, and I ultimately used NVM. Even though node -v returned the correct version, I had to use apt-get to uninstall "node" (which left NVM's version just fine). Now I have new problems, but they are unrelated.

Comment: NVM is a very good manager, just to be sure to include it in your .bashrc, you will be fine. I mostly suffer from major version changes but it is a good thing that nvm can handle everything easily.

Comment: I'm not using NVM, I'm using npm and "n", so this didn't solve my problem. If I remove node using apt-get, that also removes "npm". Not sure how to solve this.